# missing data after reading data lines

Tags: sas

I'm working on exercise 12.6 from Applied Statistics and the SAS Programming. Statment: Using column input, read NAME, GENDER, and DOB, where NAME is in columns 1-10, Gender is in column 12, and DOB is in columns 13-22. Note that with column input, you must read the date of birth as a character. You may use the following sample(I write this in my attempt).

a) Is it a good idea to define the date of birth as character? why? 
   My answer: No, isn't a good idea because we can use this date, to calculate in a straight forward way in other further equation.

b) Change DOB from character to numeric and calculate the actual date of the person.

I tried to solve the problem with this code:

```
DATA PROB12_6;                                                                                                                          

 INPUT     NAME $ 1-10                                                                                                                  
           GENDER $ 12                                                                                                                  
           DOB $  MMDDYY10. 13-22;                                                                                                            

 AGE=yrdif(input(dob,mmddyy10.),today(), 'Age');                                                                                        

DATALINES;                                                                                                                              
          1         2            

01234567890123456789012                                                                                                                 

Cody        M05/11/1981                                                                                                                 
McMaster    F11/11/1967                                                                                                                 
Bill Smith  M12/25/1999                                                                                                                 
;                                                                                                                                       


PROC PRINT DATA=PROB12_6 (FIRSTOBS=4);                                                                                                  
RUN;
```

My output is only the names, with empty value in the other variables.

I researched using absolute column pointer, but I had no luck.

Comment: Welcome. Please fully explain your objective and what your expected output is. Are you using Learning SAS by example: A programmer's guide by Ron Cody? It might help to add the full title.

Comment: DOB shouldn't be read in as character, dates are stored as numeric. You probably received an error in the log, can you post that?

Comment: Yes, that is true, but If I don't misinterpreted the exercise said that must be enter like character, and later in the code change it and use it to calculate the age. But I'm stuck in the print part, where the only print the names. I hope it is more clear now.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First Problem:

```
 DOB $ 13-22;
```

Remove the format here. You are initializing an alphanumeric variable here, and try to format it as numeric date, you can not format it this way here.

Second problem:

Maybe this is an format issue here in stackexchange, but i copied your code and to get this working i had to use this values (gender was at position 13):

```
 INPUT     NAME $ 1-10
           GENDER $ 13 
           DOB $ 14-23;
```

This results to this when i test it:

```
                            .
Cody        M   05/11/1981  34.405479452
McMaster    F   11/11/1967  47.901369863
Bill Smith  M   12/25/1999  15.780821918
```

Comment: Thanks!. I can not obtain the actual age in my program, are there any extra code, to use the data in the data line for the calculation of age?

Comment: @darioc I did Not use extracode for this result, just pasted your code and the 2 changes in my answer. Maybe you should post the log if you still get no result. I guess its a range Problem. Or did i misunderstood your comment and you mean something else?also the yrdif throws an error for the first 4 dates(because they are no real datevalues). Maybe you must lower your errorsettings here or check dob for correct date format before calling yrdif